# calculate total day in year through netsuite workflow

Tags: netsuite

Hi currently I want to just set current date is 3-3-2015 & next bill date will be 3-3-2016 how it is possible in net suite using workflow formula?could you any one tell me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Formula and the ADD_MONTHS function.

Sample formula: ADD_MONTHS({trandate}, 12)